# How can I defer or async javascript in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, opencart, deferred

I have OpenCart application. Javascripts are loaded in settings.php inside path '/catalog/controller//settings.php with similar codes as:

```
 $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/theme/<theme>/lib/lazy/jquery.lazy.1.6.min.js');
    $this->journal2->minifier->addScript('catalog/view/theme/<theme>/lib/actual/jquery.actual.min.js', 'header');
    $this->journal2->minifier->addScript('catalog/view/theme/<theme>/lib/hover-intent/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js', 'footer');
```

Here, 'theme' means theme name that is installed. I want to defer or async these javascript loading in OpenCart, how can I do it?

I know that addScript syntax has 1s parameter as file, second location, 3rd defer and 4th async where defer and async can be boolean.
I have tried statement as below to see defer false and async true:

```
 $this->journal2->minifier->addScript('catalog/view/theme/<theme>/lib/hover-intent/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js', 'footer', false, true);
```

but I am not sure if this will work or not. Please suggest

Comment: The `defer` and `async` flags will just add an attribute with the same name to the resulting `<script>` tag. What is your actual problem and what are you trying to achieve? Because `async` loading of JavaScript can result in some problems and must be done correctly. For example: a piece of code wants to use a library which isn't loaded yet.

Comment: I want to reduce javascript loading time in OpenCart. When OpenCart home page loads it has approx 27 javascript files that gets loaded which makes loading slow. I want someway to make loading fast. Thanks.

Comment: Please, for future users to know, accept an answer, if any, that best solve your question. If my answer is unclear or still didn't help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script I've been using for quite some time, in the head element.

With this you get good control of your loading of files, and can start loading anything after all the DOM is loaded, just make sure the files is not required anywhere in the DOM upon load.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript'>         

        var DomLoaded = {
            done: false, onload: [],
            loaded: function () {
                if (DomLoaded.done) return;
                DomLoaded.done = true;
                if (document.removeEventListener) { document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', DomLoaded.loaded, false); }
                for (i = 0; i < DomLoaded.onload.length; i++) DomLoaded.onload[i]();
            },
            load: function (fireThis) {
                this.onload.push(fireThis);
                if (document.addEventListener) {
                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', DomLoaded.loaded, false);
                } else {
                    /*IE<=8*/
                    if (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.opera) {
                        (function () {
                            try { document.body.doScroll('up'); return DomLoaded.loaded(); } catch (e) { }
                            if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) return DomLoaded.loaded();
                            if (!DomLoaded.done) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
                        })();
                    }
                }
                /* fallback */
                window.onload = DomLoaded.loaded;
            }
        };

        DomLoaded.load(function () {
            var d = document;
            var h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var s = d.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            s.setAttribute('async', true);
            s.setAttribute('defer', true);
            s.setAttribute('src', '/path/to/scripts.js');
            h.appendChild(s);
        });

    </script>
</head>
```

And here is a good article which describes a few more ways to speed things up, and one of them is combining your js files into 1, or 2-3-4, based on which one needs which. The benefit is less http request.

http://exisweb.net/web-site-optimization-making-javascript-load-faster

And google is filled with articles

https://www.google.com/search?q=speed%20up%20loading%20javascript%20files&rct=j

Answer (score 0):

For reducing page load times, you must do two mainly things

1. Reduce number of requests
2. Reduce package sizes

For reducing number of requests, you may merge all javascripts & css to one file. You should also applying [lazy load images](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=lazy%20load)  (This helps reduce package size too)

If you are running a VPS, you may try to install mod_pagespeed (developed by google) - It will help decrease a lot page load time.

I am not sure if you have used gtmetrix.com or http://www.webpagetest.org/
for reviewing your site speed yet.

For my experience, lazy load JavaScript will not help you much